# How to Winwait for two windows simultaneously in AutoIt?

Tags: windows, wait, autoit

I would like to know if its possible to `WinWaitActive` for `WindowWithThisTitle` and `WindowWithThatTitle` at the same time. I'm executing a command and there could be a window telling me that the connection failed or a user/pass dialog coming up.

Is there another way doing it as this?

```php
WinWaitActive("Title1", "", 5)
If(WinExists("Title1")) Then
 MsgBox(0, "", "Do something")
Else
 If(WinExists("Title2")) Then
  MsgBox(0, "", "Do something else")
 EndIf
EndIf
```

Because I don't want to have the timeout which could be more than 15 seconds.

Comment: You can see [this Autohotkey board](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/21533-multiple-winwait-at-once/) for an answer that you might be able to transfer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simpler solution might be to use a REGEX title in your `WinWaitActive` as defined [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/windowsadvanced.htm)

You would then have something like this:

```php
$hWnd = WinWaitActive("[REGEXPTITLE:(WindowWithThisTitle|WindowWithThatTitle)]")

If WinGetTitle($hWnd) = "WindowWithThisTitle" then
    DoSomething()
Else
    DoSomethingElse()
EndIf
```

Comment: The synax should be: $hWnd = WinWaitActive("[REGEXPTITLE:.*WindowWithThisTitle.*|.*WindowWithThatTitle.*]")

Answer (score 5):

How about something like this.

```php
$stillLooking = True
While $stillLooking
    $activeWindowTitle = WinGetTitle(WinActive(""))
    If $activeWindowTitle == "Title1" Then
        MsgBox(0, "", "Do something")
        $stillLooking = False
    ElseIf $activeWindowTitle == "Title2" Then
        MsgBox(0, "", "Do something else")
        $stillLooking = False
    EndIf
    sleep(5)
WEnd
```

> Because I don't want to have the
> timeout which could be more than 15
> seconds.

`WinWaitActive()` doesn't have a timeout unless you specify one. You gave it a five second timeout but you could leave that off and it would wait forever.

Comment: But this WhileLoop causes one cpu thread/core to run at 100%.
I was thinking about a solution with WinWaitActive(regex) but I dont know how to create a regex that has an OR operator. Any Idea?
What do you mean with "Don't forget to vote!" btw?

Comment: The sleep(5) - or more - will fix the cpu problem, it was hard looping.  WinWaitActive() wont do multiple targets and its return is a simple success bool so you can't really regex it.  You have voted once since you started using stack overflow. The StackOverflow system really only works if people vote.  If a question or answer is helpful to you you can vote it up with the up arrow picture or down with the down arrow. Good luck, hope this helped if it did you could show that by voting.

Comment: I didn't yet mark your answer as "THE" answer because maybe someone knows a method without looping. I'll just wait some time and then set it as answer if no one can provide a better way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: WinWaitActive() also loops in the code of that function. I have a hard time imagining any way to do anything like this without looping in a procedural (vs. event driven) context.  I'm sure a better way to do this exists but that way is also likely to have a loop in it.

Comment: I agree, being a procedural environment, this would be nearly impossible to accomplish without looping. I typically have my long running AutoIt loops sleep for an 1/8th of a second: Sleep(125) This polls often enough for most needs, and doesn't hog the CPU cycles.

Comment: I agree John, I usually do 200 or more in real world applications.  A window typically will not come into focus and then leave focus in a time shorter then that. I just wanted to show that any sleep even a short one will solve it.  Thanks for the +1!

Comment: According to official AutoIt documentation for `WinWaitActive`, ["The window is polled every 250 milliseconds or so."](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWaitActive.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Functions for two windows ..

```
; #FUNCTION# ====================================================================================================================
; Name...........: _2WinWait
; Description ...: Wait For Tow Windows .
; Syntax.........: _2WinWait ($FirstTitle,$SecondTitle,[$FirstText = "" ,[$SecondText = ""]] )
; Parameters ....: $FirstTitle  - Title Of First  Wondow 
;                  $SecondTitle - Title Of Second Wondow 
;                  $FirstText   - Text  Of First  Wondow 
;                  $SecondText  - Text  Of Second Wondow 
; Return values .: Success - None
;                  Failure - Returns a 0 => If Your Titles Is Wrong
; Author ........: Ashalshaikh : Ahmad Alshaikh
; Remarks .......: 
; Related .......:
; Link ..........;
; Example .......; No
; ===============================================================================================================================
Func _2WinWait ($FirstTitle,$SecondTitle,$FirstText = "" ,$SecondText = "" )
    If $FirstTitle = "" Or $SecondTitle = "" Then
        Return 0 
    Else
        Do 
        Until WinExists ($FirstTitle,$FirstText) Or WinExists ($SecondTitle,$SecondText)
    EndIf
EndFunc


; #FUNCTION# ====================================================================================================================
; Name...........: _2WinWait_Any 
; Description ...: Wait For Tow Windows And Return Any Window Id Exists .
; Syntax.........: _2WinWait_Any ($FirstTitle,$SecondTitle,[$FirstText = "" ,[$SecondText = ""]] )
; Parameters ....: $FirstTitle  - Title Of First  Wondow 
;                  $SecondTitle - Title Of Second Wondow 
;                  $FirstText   - Text  Of First  Wondow 
;                  $SecondText  - Text  Of Second Wondow 
; Return values .: Success - Number Of Window ==> 1= First Window , 2= Second Window
;                  Failure - Returns a 0 => If Your Titles Is Wrong
; Author ........: Ashalshaikh : Ahmad Alshaikh
; Remarks .......: 
; Related .......:
; Link ..........;
; Example .......; No
; ===============================================================================================================================
Func _2WinWait_Any ($FirstTitle,$SecondTitle,$FirstText = "" ,$SecondText = "" )
    If $FirstTitle = "" Or $SecondTitle = "" Then
        Return 0 
    Else
        Do 
        Until WinExists ($FirstTitle,$FirstText) Or WinExists ($SecondTitle,$SecondText)
        If WinExists ($FirstTitle,$FirstTexit) Then 
            Return 1 
        Else
            Return 2 
        EndIf
    EndIf
EndFunc
```

[**for more with examples**](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=101034&view=findpost&p=720111)

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to *autoit* and the programming world in general and I had this same dilemma.  Luckily I figured out a straight fwd way to do it:

```php
Do
$var1 = 0
If  WinGetState("Document Reference","")    Then
    $var1 = 1
ElseIf  WinGetState("Customer Search","")   Then
    $var1 = 1
EndIf
Until $var1 = 1
```

So it'll stay in the loop until it finds the window and sets `$var1` to `1`.  There's probably easier ways (I'm sure developers are gasping at this) but this is straight fwd enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an infinite while loop with if statements in there:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Example()

Func Example()
    While 1
        ; Test if the window exists and display the results.
        If WinExists("Windows Security") Then
            Local $hWnd = WinWaitActive("Windows Security", "", 2000)
            ControlSetText($hWnd, "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]", "hel233")
            ControlClick("Windows Security","","[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]")
            Sleep(5000)
        EndIf

        ; Test if the window exists and display the results.
        If WinExists("Spread the Word") Then
            'The line below will wait until the window is active, but we don't need that
            'Local $hWnd = WinWaitActive("Spread the Word", "", 2000)
            WinClose("Spread the Word")
            Sleep(5000)
        EndIf



    wend
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

The RegExp solution is nice, but it has the following downsides:

- RegExps are quite slow and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary;
- It's not very handy and clean if more windows are needed;
- It doesn't allow to use [different properties to identify windows](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/windowsadvanced.htm#:%7E:text=.-,Advanced%20Window%20Descriptions).

The following function allows you to wait for any number of windows using different identifiers:

```php
Func WinWaitActiveMultiple(Const ByRef $avTitles, Const $asTexts = 0)
    Local Const $ciNumWindows = UBound($avTitles)
    Local Const $ciWaitDelay = Opt("WinWaitDelay")

    While True
        For $i = 0 To $ciNumWindows - 1
            Local $sText = ($asTexts = 0)? "": $asTexts[$i]
            Local $hWnd = WinActive($avTitles[$i], $sText)
            If $hWnd Then
                Return $hWnd
            EndIf
        Next
        Sleep($ciWaitDelay)
    WEnd
EndFunc
```

It works very similar to `WinWaitActive()`, but accepts arrays. It can be used as follows:

```php
Local Const $casWinTitles = [ _
    "Title 1", "Title 2", "[CLASS:WClass1]" _
]
Local Const $casWinTexts = ["Text 1", "", ""]

Local $hWnd = WinWaitActiveMultiple($casWinTitles, $casWinTexts)
Local $sTitle = WinGetTitle($hWnd)

If $sTitle == "Title 1" Then
    ; Handle window 1

ElseIf $sTitle == "Title 2" Then
    ; Handle window 2

Else
    ; Handle window 3

EndIf
```